# ubuntu 15.10 not loading desktop

Tags: boot

ubuntu boots past the desktop login screen to  a screen with a white Gear Icon. I have been through recovery mode twice,  once to repair packages, once to  read all files. Recovery mode did an update on several packages, removed a few, then.... reboot to same screen  with the white Gear Icon.
Does anyone know why it continues past the login screen to the white Gear Icon screen?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by user....booted up in recovery mode, changed desktop background and realized login input was now available yet hidden with different desktop background. Luckily moving mouse around showed the login / password input menu.

Anyone that may have read this will realize this user is relatively new to Linux and Ubuntu. Background in Windows. Again, luckily Ubuntu appears to have some excellent support resources.

Has my floundering messed up anything critical? Time will tell, or my much younger support expert will I'm sure let me know!